# No. of critical points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Domain: $\mathopen]1,4\mathclose[$, $f(x)= 3x^2 - 6x$
How many critical points exist?
(Zero, 1, 3, 4)

By diff.($x$):
$f'(x)= 6x-6$
Then $x=1$ is local point of minimum, but according to the interval should I consider it or not as a critical point?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Amgeeed! I'm afraid I can't make sense of your post, please view https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a quick guide to MathJax

Comment: Accordingly, it seems the OP is using the French-style of interval notation, meaning that $]1,4[$ is equivalent to writing the interval $(1,4) = \{x\in\mathbb R \;\;|\;\; 1 < x < 4\}$. In particular, @Amgeeed, since the function is not defined at $x=1$, that critical point must be excluded, showing you that there are **zero** critical points.

Answer (score 0):

A function maps a domain (a set) to another set.  A function is not only defined by how it maps points but also by *WHICH* points (the domain) are mapped and indicating what the domain is an *essential* aspect of defining a function.

That means the function $f: ]1,4[ \to \mathbb R$ via $f(x) = 3x^2 - 6x$ is a *DIFFERENT* function than $\overline{f}:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ via $\overline{f}(x) = 3x^2 - 6x$.

So $x = 1$ can not be a critical point of $f$ because $x = 1$ is not a point in $f$'s domain at all.